# IPtables on CentOS 6

Tags: interface, centos, ip, iptables, forward

Please help me out a little bit. I've inherited a firewall made of CentOS 6 and I'm a bit affraid to modify the iptables at all, but I have to do it for a task.

The tanks is to make one client in the office accessable from the internet but only on one port. Internet comes on the interface ppp0, clients are being serverd on the eth1. And I have to forward the port 80 to 3000. And our public IP to the clients IP. :D Sounds secure and easy right?

I've come up with a sollution, but I'm affraid to give it a go until I'm sure. Please make me sure of it. :D

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.2.3:3000
```

Comment: That's a decent question. However, Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions and questions on *using*  Linux are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

This question would be more appropriate for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: OK, thank you. BTW: Got sorted it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i ppp0 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.2.3:3000
```

Do not apply this to the 80th port because then all the clients will be unable to browse the internet, because they are also using the 80th port. :D